# sending bulk sms using springMVC

Tags: java, sms

I am developing an application in wihch involvees sending sms to many mobiles using Spring MVC. Can anyone please help me in this regard. Please also tell me the if any hardware component required, for now i am using a SMS Gateway.

Comment: Retagging - Spring is not relevant to this. It has no SMS functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Here nothing to do with Spring MVC as server side you need to handle the load. Better have look SMSLib http://smslib.org/. SMSLib support bulk SMS handling and you can go with GSM Modem or SMS Gateway.